# Trying to check on hours AND minutes specific in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check on weekday, hour and minutes so I can make a small open closed thing.
So far I tried this

```
      var todayMins = new Date().getMinutes();
  var today = new Date().getHours();
  var weekday = new Date().getDay();
  if (weekday >= 1 && weekday <= 3) {
      if (today >= 7 && today <= 19 || todayMins >= 30) {
        if (todayMins >= 0 && todayMins <= 30){
         $("#changer").addClass('groen');
         document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Open";
        }
        else {
        $("#changer").addClass('red');
        document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Gesloten";
      }
      }

  }
```

so for example if its a wednesday and its past 19:30 it should be "gesloten".
How can I do this?

Comment: MomentJS library could help you to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) is recommended if you're doing a lot of date / time handling. But if this is a one-off, you can use vanilla JS to do the check:

```js
$(function() {

  var now = new Date(),
    day = now.getDay(),
    hours = now.getHours(),
    mins = now.getMinutes(),
    isOpen = false,
    startTimes = [
      null,                 // Sunday
      { hour: 7, min: 30},  // Monday
      { hour: 7, min: 30},  // Tuesday
      { hour: 7, min: 30},  // Wednesday
      { hour: 7, min: 30},  // Thursday
      { hour: 7, min: 30},  // Friday
      null                  // Saturday
      ],
    endTimes = [
      null,                 // Sunday
      { hour: 19, min: 30}, // Monday
      { hour: 19, min: 30}, // Tuesday
      { hour: 19, min: 30}, // Wednesday
      { hour: 19, min: 30}, // Thursday
      { hour: 19, min: 30}, // Friday
      null                  // Saturday
      ];
      
      // check we have opening times for the given day
      if (startTimes[day] !== null &&
          endTimes[day] !== null) {
          
        // check it's not too early
        if (hours > startTimes[day].hour || 
           (hours === startTimes[day].hour && mins >= startTimes[day].min)) {
          
          // check it's not too late
          if (hours < endTimes[day].hour || 
              (hours === endTimes[day].hour && mins < endTimes[day].min)) {
              isOpen = true;
          }
          
        }
          
      }
      
  // update open / closed status
  if (isOpen) {
    $("#changer").addClass('groen');
    document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Open";
  } else {
    $("#changer").addClass('red');
    document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Gesloten";
  }

});
```

```css
.groen {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="changer"></div>
```

**EDIT**:

When I initially read your question, it sounded as though you only wanted this to apply on Wednesdays, so the 'day of week' check discounts anything other than that day.  If you actually meant to perform the check on different days, you'll need to edit the `day == 3` section.

For instance, if you want to apply the check between Monday and Wednesday inclusive, use `(day >= 1 && day <=3)` (although note, this will mean the result will show "Open" for any time during Thursday to Sunday, which probably isn't what you want).

**EDIT 2**: 
Code updated to check start / end times on weekdays.

**EDIT 3**:
Code updated again to handle multiple start / end times during the week.

Comment: I'll use else if statement for the rest of the weekdays so it would be something like else if ((day == 5 && day == 6) && (hours > 19 || hours < 7 || (hours == 19 && mins >= 30))){ $("#changer").addClass('red');
    document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Gesloten";}

Comment: But I also have different opening times how can I solve those? as we only did the closing time now

Comment: See edited code - change the `startHour` / `startMinute` to specify a different start time.  As the code stands, this should check the current time is between a given start and end time between Monday-Friday.

Comment: The thing is you assumed that the opening times from monday through friday are exactly the same everyday, but that is not the thing here. Monday tuesday and wednesday have their own times, I tried adding that but it doesn't work

Comment: startHour2 = 7,
        startMinute2 = 30,
        endHour2 = 17,
        endMinute2 = 30;

    if (day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3){
      if (hours > startHour2 || 
          (hours === startHour2 && mins >= startMinute2)) {
          
        // check it's not too late
        if (hours < endHour2 || 
            (hours === endHour2 && mins < endMinute2)) {
            isOpen = true;
        }
          
      }
    }

Comment: With respect, that wasn't made clear in the original question.  See updated code above - this should allow you to set your preferred opening / closing times for each day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Weekdays start from 0 . Means Sunday= 0 to Saturday=6 . According to your code it will check only from Monday to Wednesday.

```
if (today <= 7 && today >= 19 ) {
      if (todayMins > 30){
        $("#changer").addClass('red');
        document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Gesloten";
     }    
    else{
     $("#changer").addClass('groen');
     document.getElementById("changer").innerHTML = "Open";
  }
}
```

You can write like this also so for a particular day if the time cross 19.30 then it will change to 'gesloten'

Comment: As it stands, this would cause 'gesolten' to appear for 7:30+, 8:30+, 9:30+ etc, etc.

Comment: My bad @Conan todays date will be greater then only . not equals to. I modified .

Comment: The minutes check was OK - `>= 30` is fine, as we want 'gesolten` to appear either on the half-hour or past it. Problem is that it will apply to all hours between 7AM and 7PM (for instance, it will show 'gesolten' if the time is 10:38AM).

Comment: yes you are correct . i should change the getHour condition. Thanks.